# Is a return of 'false' a valid postcondition of a method?

Tags: java, oop, design-by-contract

I've been learning about postconditions, preconditions, and design by contract recently and I haven't been able to find an exact answer to this question.

To me, a postcondition seems to essentially be 'what the method is meant to have achieved' after being invoked.

Here's an example

```
//If x is not equal to y, do something with x and return true. Otherwise, return false.

public boolean example(int x)
{
    if(x != y)
    {
        return true;
        //do something with x.
    }
    else
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

When stating the postconditions of this method, would it make sense to say that it returning 'false' is one of them? Or is the postcondition only what is done with x?

Edit:

Here's a better example with an actual precondition -

```
public boolean example2(Example x)
{
    if (x == a)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("x must not be the same as a");
    }

    if(x != y)
    {
        return true;
        //do something with x.
    }
    else
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide any preconditions nor postconditions in your `example` method. What you provided was a class invariant.

The precondition is checked in the method before the postcondition is checked. Often times this is done via `assert` for post-conditions.

> A postcondition states what a method ensures if it has been called by
>   fulfilling its precondition. If the postcondition is violated although
>   the precondition holds, the method (the supplier) has broken the
>   contract (implementation error). In other words a postcondition is a
>   right to the customer and an obligation to the supplier.

Quote source: https://c4j-team.github.io/C4J/examples_postcondition.html

You are not returning `true` or `false` typically. The postcondition is handled by assertions. The Oracle page on this gives good [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7930/assert-13/index.html):

```
   /**
     * Returns a BigInteger whose value is (this-1 mod m).
     *
     * @param  m the modulus.
     * @return this-1 mod m.
     * @throws ArithmeticException  m <= 0, or this BigInteger
     *         has no multiplicative inverse mod m (that is, this BigInteger
     *         is not relatively prime to m).
     */
    public BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger m) {
        if (m.signum <= 0)
          throw new ArithmeticException("Modulus not positive: " + m);
        if (!this.gcd(m).equals(ONE))
          throw new ArithmeticException(this + " not invertible mod " + m);

        ... // Do the computation

        assert this.multiply(result).mod(m).equals(ONE);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: OK. So if I had this same method, but with an exception if a precondition is failed before the x!= y check, would the return of false in that check be a postcondition of the method, or only the return of true + whatever it does with the argument? Apologies if I'm not providing enough useful information here.

Comment: @stuckpixels: You would throw an exception. True or false wouldn't be returned. That would be a part of the contract. There would be no postcondition until the precondition is satisfied. For instance, throw an exception if `x` is too large.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, pre+postconditions can be anything, that verifies, that the given interface follows the required behaviour.

As an example:
`List<E>` is an interface. `ArrayList<E>` is a class, implementing `List<E>` and exposing expected behaviour. Imagine, you write a set of [JUnit](http://junit.org/) tests against `List<E>` and then execute them against `ArrayList<E>`. If your `ArrayList<E>` passes the test - it satisfies the contract of list behaviour.

```
`
//Precondition
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
//Postcondition: a newly created list must be empty, if you did not put anything there
assertEquals(0,objectList.size);
//Precondition
Object someObject = new Object();
//Precondition
objectList.add(someObject);
//Postcondition: you get exactly the same element, that you have just put
assertEquals(1,objectList.size);
assertEquals(someObject,objectList.get(0));
`
```

In your case you have the following:

Precondition: `x=something, but not equal to y`
Postcondition: `example(x) is true`